# QT Creator расположение файла для запуска

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtcreator

Скачал Qt Creator архивом, не могу найти где у него находится исполняемый файл для запуска. Скачивал для Windows.

Comment: А вы случайно не исходники скачали?

Answer (score 0):

Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin здесь смотрели?

Comment: нет такого пути

Comment: Воспользоваться поиском Windows для файла "qtcreator.exe"